# Converting integer value to unicode for labeling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, unicode

It is possible to stylize a layer with integer numbers stored in a shapefile and then choose a symbol out of a font.

I would like to use the label engine instead, because i'm more flexible, for example i can rotate the label.

Is it possible to label a point layer with unicode numbers stored as integer within a shapefile?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question properly. It is possible to use an integer field for labelling: just select the field you need inside the labelling tool. Therefore, no conversion to unicode is necessary.

Comment: I was able to do it with the function editor, but i'm not able to use mini-Mardown formatting..grrrr  :"""
Converts Integer Values from Shapefile to Unicode Values

Important: No Values above 256 allowed!
For dkmSSB define a query to get rid of the values above 200.
These values are just used for labeling.


"""


from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *



@qgsfunction(args=1, group='Custom')


def INTtoUNICODE(values, feature, parent):


 value = values[0]

 return chr(value)

Comment: Could you please edit your initial post and add either a screenshot or the code you have written in the function editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it with the function editor. This is the code:

```python
""" Converts Integer Values from Shapefile to Unicode Values
Important: No Values above 256 allowed! For dkmSSB define a query to
get rid of the values above 200. These values are just used for
labeling. """

from qgis.core import
from qgis.gui import

@qgsfunction(args=1, group='Custom')

def INTtoUNICODE(values, feature, parent):

value = values[0]

    return chr(value)
```

Then choose custom functions: `INTtoUNICODE("Fieldname")`